# Correcting a list with a dictionary and a subsequent .sort() command displays wrong string order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

sorry for the bad title. I am new to programming and I could not come up with a better description.

So, I have this code:

```
umw = {'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14}

def card_ranks(ranks):
    "Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
    for i in ranks:
        if i in umw:
            index = ranks.index(i)
            ranks[index] = str(umw[i])

    ranks.sort(reverse = True)
    return ranks

print(card_ranks(['A', '3', '4', 'K'])) #should output [14, 13, 4, 3]
```

This gives me the following result:

```
['4', '3', '14', '13']
```

clearing the "reverse = True" gives the following:

```
['13', '14', '3', '4']
```

If i do something like that:

```
r = card_ranks(['A', '3', '4', 'K'])
r[0] -> gives me '4'
but this doesnt work again:
print(sorted(r)) -> gives me ['4', '3', '14', '13'] all over again.
```

So it seems, that the .sort() command views the 13 & 14 as a unit and the 3 & 4.

Could somebody explain why that is?

Thanks alot!

Comment: because the string `"13"` is not the same as the number `13`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sorting strings where `'11'` comes before `'3'`. The following [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) call deals with the necessary type conversion:

```
def card_ranks(ranks):
    return sorted((umw[c] if c in umw else int(c) for c in ranks), reverse=True)

>>> card_ranks(['A', '3', '4', 'K'])
[14, 13, 4, 3]
```

For every string in `ranks`, the generator expression produces the corresponding value in the `umw` dict or, as fallback, turns the string into an `int`, such that a proper numerical, non-lexicographical comparison is possible.

Answer (score 6):

You're sorting them lexicographically, as strings rather than numbers.  You could convert them to integers first, or you could expand your `umw` dictionary:

```
umw = {str(i): i for i in range(2, 10)}
umw.update({'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14})

def card_ranks(ranks):
    return sorted(ranks, key=umw.get, reverse=True)

card_ranks(['A', '3', '4', 'K'])
# ['A', 'K', '4', '3']
```

This uses the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method as a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) to guide the sorting without changing the values being sorted.

Comment: Hey Patrick, thank you for your answer. I especially like the first line. Is this something called a Dictionary Comprehension? I know list comprehensions, but never saw something like that...

Comment: Yes, `{str(i): i for i in range(2, 10)}` is a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

It does not see them as a unit, it compares the charakter for charakter:
`'1'<'3'<'4'`, so the ranking is `'13'<'14'<'3'<'4'`

You want all of them to be numbers, so change the following lines:

```
ranks[index] = str(umw[i])
```

to

```
ranks[index] = umw[i]
```

and:

```
print(card_ranks(['A', '3', '4', 'K']))
```

to

```
print(card_ranks(['A', 3, 4, 'K']))
```

Answer (score 1):

- Because the list elements are string that's why
- while sorting its taking in account every character i.e. every digit in the number
- Which means every string char is sorted by its first character and then by its next character
- Which means `"233" < "3"` and `"1111" < "233"`

  ```
  umw = {'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14}

  def card_ranks(ranks):
      "Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
      for i in ranks:
          if i in umw:
              index = ranks.index(i)
              ranks[index] = str(umw[i])
      ranks = list(map(int, ranks))   # The line to be added
      ranks.sort(reverse = True)
      return ranks

  print(card_ranks(['A', '3', '4', 'K'])) #sh
  ```

  - You need to convert the list elements to int by `ranks = list(map(int, ranks))` before sorting the list

Answer (score 0):

```
ranks[index] = str(umw[i])
```

You are saving the values as strings instead of integers.  And it is sorting them as strings.

Try

```
ranks[index] = int(umw[i])
```